# How to implement guided motion along 3 axes(For a switch of sorts) in Custom View Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-custom-view, user-experience

Please refer to the screenshot images attached, The below image [image: first image] shows Google Pay app.There is only 1 axis and the circle button can slide along that axis only.

What I require is 3 axes( as T or Y as seen in the second image) and a circle button that can slide along all those axes.

I understand this can be done using **Custom View** in Android. 
However, *I need help in writing a custom algorithm to define the motion of the circle button along those axes.*`

Second image - hand drawn mockup
[image: hand drawnmock up]

Comment: see [linear equation written in parametric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Parametric_form) or [here](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-linear-quadratic-relations/0/steps/12128) (with some images)

Comment: thank you I see the merit of using a parametric equation, currently using an onclickDragListener now to move the circle, not sure how we can ' guide' the movement of the circle based on an equation ?  Is there a certain method/ function that I'm missing ?

Comment: yes: you need a [custom view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) - there is no existing view that could be used for what you want

Comment: Pardon the repeated enquiry, but could you please elaborate with some pesudocode ?

Comment: did you follow the link i gave you? did you read `"Implementing custom drawing"` and `"Making the view interactive"` subpages (on the left below `"Custom view components"` main page? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: Thank you pskink, I did go thru the link, however the GestureDetector does a poor job of guiding our circle shape to the 'action' points...please see this link to understand the kind of movement we are looking for - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WD9Zh4oIiQ

Comment: you dont need `GestureDetector` - just use [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent) API directly - `getX()` / `getY()` methods

Comment: Thank you, shall look into it and get back.